# Is it possible to create Stress Test using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTest Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a WebService in ASP.NET and need to write Stress Test now. 
I have loadtest in my project now. I added them using wizard in VS2013 Ultimate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx 
But now I want to move from VS Ultimate to VS Professional which has not this feature.

My Question: Can I create Load Test programly using [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtest.aspx)?

If yes, can you provide me examples of creating and using?

If no, Is any alternatives inside VS?

loadtest is working OK now and using this method:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("template.jpg")]
public void MultithreadedProcessorUsingTest()
   {
      WebService1SoapClient _service = new WebService1SoapClient();
      string testImagePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "template.jpg");
      byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(testImagePath);
      var data = _service.UploadImage(image);
      int currentProcNumber = data.processInfo.processNumber;
      Assert.Fail(currentProcNumber.ToString());            
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Web and Load tests are only supported in the Ultimate editions.

By using the controller and agent software, download it from Microsoft, you can run load tests on computers that do not have Visual Studio Ultimate.